# Git reindex untracked added files in remote repository

Tags: git, indexing, repository, git-bare

i have --bare remote repository. files in dev folder and hook post-receive from dev.git folder. now my developers sometimes change and ftp code strait in dev folder. changes doesn't appear when i clone pull or checkout repository, is there a way to reindex remote hard changes?

Comment: The whole point of a bare repository is that it has no working copy. Of course it doesn't notice when files are changed in some arbitrary directory! Do you want to have your developers making commits directly on the development server? (Unless you've got a very good reason, I would strongly discourage this.)

Comment: As I mentioned on your previous question, please consider wording this better. Preferably with names and a proper title so that it becomes useful to others rather than a one shot question.

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
rm .git/index
git reset
git add .
git commit
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run `git rm -r --cached . && git add . && git commit -am 'reindexed files'`